# iOS Open Visual Voicemail with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a way within my application to download voice mails. As of right now a user must manually go into his/her phone app and saved from there.

Is there a way to open Visual Voicemail with Swift, or at the very least the phone app without adding a phone number?

Comment: No, you have no control over such things in iOS.

Comment: I did not think so, just hoping.